# openlayers map toggle layer not working in ff27 + 28

Tags: firefox, openlayers

I´m fighting with a strange bug. An internal application is based on Openlayers 2.11, GeoExt-1.1, ext-3.4.0. One menu Button toggles the visibility of a vector based layer. This works good in all Browsers except Firefox 27 + 28.

Here the Layer is only rendered ionce at pageLoad, if I hide it by click it disappears but doesn´t show again on second click to make it visible again. It will show again when I zoom into the map [most likely this acts as a refresh to the map]. Firebug gives me no error. I thought maybe it´s some problem with origin policies but couldn´t find any blocked content.

Does anyone heart of a bug toggling layers with openlayers in FF 27 + 28?

Thankful for your help,

t book

Answer (score 0):

My problem can be solved by upgrading openlayers to 2.12